# Search in an AD using a user from another AD with java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap-query

I have two Active Directory in two domains: domain1.xx and domain2.xx 
I have a user that belongs to domain1.xx named user1.
I can do LDAP queries on the domain1 using the user1.
The user1 has a read right on domain2.xx and i have tested that with AD Explorer and it worked.
The problem is when i use java, it returns me this exception:
ERROR: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece

this the code connecting querying in domain1 and that it works:

```
package ad;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class AD {


    static DirContext ldapAuthenticate(String password, String userdn) throws Exception {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userdn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        //connect to my domain controller
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://domain1.xx");
        //Create the initial directory context
        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {

            ctx =  new javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext(env);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
                       //something went wrong
            ///handle in some way
        }
        return ctx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DirContext context = ldapAuthenticate("xxxxxx","user01@domain1.xx");
        String userdn = "dc=domain1,dc=xx";
        SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attributes = {"member"};
        searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

        //Change the NameOfGroup for the group name you would like to retrieve the members of.
        String filter ="objectclass=*";
        NamingEnumeration values = context.search(userdn, filter, null);

        //Loop through the search results
        while (values.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) values.next();
            System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
            javax.naming.directory.Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

            if (null != attrs) {
                for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();) {
                    Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                    String attributeID = atr.getID();
                    Enumeration vals = atr.getAll();

                    if (vals.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String username = (String) vals.nextElement();
                        System.out.println("Username: " + username);

                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No members for groups found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to query the domain2.xx I had the exception:

```
package ad;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class AD {


    static DirContext ldapAuthenticate(String password, String userdn) throws Exception {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userdn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        //connect to my domain controller
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://domain2.xx");
        //Create the initial directory context
        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {

            ctx =  new javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext(env);

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
                       //something went wrong
            ///handle in some way
        }
        return ctx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DirContext context = ldapAuthenticate("xxxxxx","user01@domain1.xx");
        String userdn = "dc=domain2,dc=xx";
        SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attributes = {"member"};
        searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

        //Change the NameOfGroup for the group name you would like to retrieve the members of.
        String filter ="objectclass=*";
        NamingEnumeration values = context.search(userdn, filter, null);

        //Loop through the search results
        while (values.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) values.next();
            System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
            javax.naming.directory.Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

            if (null != attrs) {
                for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();) {
                    Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                    String attributeID = atr.getID();
                    Enumeration vals = atr.getAll();

                    if (vals.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String username = (String) vals.nextElement();
                        System.out.println("Username: " + username);

                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No members for groups found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this case. user01@domain1.xx can read all OU in domain2.xx i have tried that with AD explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication error you posted contains special code that can be useful. In your case, the code is 525 (*AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525*). Code 525 means "User not found". Judging by your code you are reusing the same user  - *user1@domain1*. This user EXISTS only in domain 1. Domain 2 is not aware of this user so AD domain controller rejects the authentication attempt.

Code samples attached to the question operates against specific domain controllers and not global catalogs. Try to do the following:

- use InitialLdapContext instead of InitialDirContext
- bind to Global Catalog instead of Domain Controller. To do so use URL *ldap://FQDN:3268*. Please not the port is 3268.

Please note that port 3268 is not secure.

Hope this helps.